# Entity Framework not to insert/update certain column ( but still column should be mapped )

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I know I can exclude column from mapping using `NotMapped` attribute or Fluent API, but that's not exactly what I want.

let's say, I have and object of type `Customer` and than I want to check the following:

```
if (customer.UpgradeVersion < 2)   // some condition
{
    context.Entry(customer).Property(c => c.MyProperty).IsModified = false;
}
```

This will exclude property from `UPDATE` statement in case when customer is modified, but it doesn't work for `INSERT`-s.

Ideally, I would like to conditionally 'unmap' property for certain object, so that it's not inserted/updated/validated against its validation attributes, etc.

Actually, I can override `ValidateEntity` of `DbContext` + workaround updates using `IsModifed` flag, but `inserts`-s are the main problem...

Comment: what should the property's value in the database table be if a new customer row is inserted? DBNull?

Comment: What about make a custom attribute to handle it?

Comment: @Alex, the point is that database table may not contain the column at all - that's roughly what is actually checked by condition. So, the statement `INSERT INTO customer(id, ..., MyProperty)` will fail, even if parameter value is DBNull.

Comment: @ggui, can I have an example? Seems like I have to override SQL-generation

Answer (score 0):

Create a partial class and add the additional properties that you want to the Customer entity.  Those properties will only exist at the object level.  You can also add methods that way too.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with actually using multiple DB contexts for that + some fluent API.
The main idea is:

1. Create a new db-context and pass supported `UpgradeVersion` as parameter
2. Use fluent API and some reflection to only map the properties with upgrade version >= `SupportedUpgradeVersion` parameter

I believe that's the only way to achieve what I wanted. You cannot do it with a single DB context.